# Rails Routing Error with using namespace - uninitialized constant for the namespace path

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, namespaces, routes

I'm using rails 4.1.6 and I think I should missing something

I setup the routes with namespace

**config/routes.rb**

```
namespace :manage do
  root to: "dashboard#index"
end
```

and then I try to visit `/manage` page, I should get an exception about Manage::DashboardController (I haven't created it yet), but actually I get the following:

```
uninitialized constant Manage
```

I can't fix it even I read the related source code, look like it's caused by the `module` option, I can get the same error for `/manage/users` if I change it to:

```
scope path: 'manage', module: "manage" do
  resources :users
end
```

Answer (score 1):

it works after I create an empty directory "manage" under `app/controllers`